# Highcharts Belgium map not loading

Tags: highcharts

```js
 createPulseMap(res, country) {
    console.log(res, country, 'coutntren')
  let mapDatas = [];
    let mapValue = [];
    country = country == 'All' ? 'WORLD' : country;
  const d = this.healthReportService.formatLocationDeatails(res);

  console.log(d, 'country data');
   d.forEach((e) => {
     console.log(e.country)
      let imageUrl = DataConstants.MAP_STATUS_LIST_PULSE[e.tagStatus][e.siteType];
   mapValue.push({
        marker: {
          symbol: imageUrl,
        },
        lat: parseFloat(e.siteLat),
        
        lon: parseFloat(e.siteLong),
        country: e.country,
        stateName: e.state,
        capacity: e.capacity,
        dcCapacity: e.dcCapacity,
        invertersCount: e.invertersCount,
        assetAvailability: e.assetAvailability,
        tagStatus: e.tagStatus
      });
      

    });
    console.log(mapValue, 'mapvalue')
    mapDatas.push({
      mapData: map[country],
      borderWidth: 0,
      nullColor: '#B2B2B2',
      showInLegend: false
    });
    console.log(mapDatas, 'mapdatanew')
    for (let key in DataConstants.MAP_STATUS_LIST_PULSE) {
      mapDatas.push({
        type: 'mappoint',
        showInLegend: true,
        stickyTracking: false,
        color: '#897d93',
        name: DataConstants.MAP_STATUS_LIST_PULSE[key].name,
        data: mapValue.filter(data => key + "" === data.tagStatus + ""),
        marker: {
          itemStyle: {
            fontSize: '35px'
          },
          radius: 5,
          symbol: 'circle'
        }
      });
    }
    console.log(mapDatas, country, 'mapdata and country')
    return this.initiateHighMap(mapDatas, country);
  }

  initiateHighMap(mapDatas, country) {
   let options = {
      chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
        style: {
          fontFamily: "Roboto,sans-serif"
        }
      

      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      legend: {
        itemStyle: {
          fontSize: '13px',
          fontWeight: 'none',
          color: '#4d4d4d'
        },
        align: 'left',
        floating: false,
        itemMarginBottom: 0,
        itemMarginTop: 5
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: mapDatas,
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      }
    };
    return options;
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGNTv.png)

Hi,
I am using Highcharts static maps. I am facing problem with Belgium map. Other country maps are loading properly but when i select Belgium country then highcharts is throwing error as **"Highcharts error #22: www.highcharts.com/errors/22"**. Can you please suggest me what needs to be done so that map loads without issue and without changing highcharts version

Comment: put your code in jsFiddle so we can run and test what is the issue..

Comment: Hi @Prashanth, The basic example with Belgium map works correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9utLwrsj/. According to the error message you should use `Proj4js` library. Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi @ Ppotaczek, Thanks for ur reply. i tried to use Proj4.js, but I am getting confused in using it in angular 5 project. I just need to include the file in package.json or need to use it in component for map to display?




Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @ Umair, Thank you for ur reply. Ill add it in jsFiddle and share the link.

Comment: Hi i have added ts code. please let me know if anything is wrong in this

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. Please check an example from `highcharts-angular` wrapper that uses proj4.js: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/blob/0bc755a585e4134ca48f7bed13d559069cebb65b/src/app/app.component.ts#L9